# Angularjs ng-aa authenticated: true is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication

i use `ng-aa` for user login & signup in `angularjs`.
But when I defined state dashboard and defined property authenticated: true but it is not check weather user login or not.

Without login if i try to access dashboard then it is redirect to dashboard.

Thanks in advance.

here is the code of `config.router.js`:

```
'use strict';
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $timeout) {
    // add listener for change page title and parent menu activation
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;


    // Activate loading indicator
    var stateChangeStartEvent = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function ()
    {
        $rootScope.loadingProgress = true;
    });

    // De-activate loading indicator
    var stateChangeSuccessEvent = $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function ()
    {
        $timeout(function ()
        {
            $rootScope.loadingProgress = false;
        });
    });

    // Store state in the root scope for easy access
    $rootScope.state = $state;
    // Cleanup

    $rootScope.$on('$destroy', function ()
    {
        stateChangeStartEvent();
        stateChangeSuccessEvent();
    });

}).config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $authProvider, $mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider, site_settings, $httpProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $mdIconProvider.defaultIconSet('assets/angular-material-assets/img/icons/sets/core-icons.svg', 24);

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('pink')
            .accentPalette('orange')
            .warnPalette('red')
            .backgroundPalette('blue-grey');

    $authProvider.signinUrl = site_settings.api_url + 'authenticate';
    $authProvider.signinState = 'login';
    $authProvider.signinRoute = '/login';
    $authProvider.signinTemplateUrl = 'app/modules/authenticate/views/login.html';
    $authProvider.afterSigninRedirectTo = 'dashboard';
    $authProvider.afterSignoutRedirectTo = 'login';


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector) {
        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go('temp');
    });

    $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                abstract: true,
                //url: '/',
                views: {
                    '@': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/modules/general/views/dashboard.html',
                        controller: 'DashBoardController'
                    },
                    'toolbar@index': {templateUrl: 'app/modules/general/views/toolbar.html', },
                    'navigation@index': {templateUrl: 'app/modules/general/views/navigation.html', },
                },
                resolve: {
                    dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                        function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['app/modules/general/DashBoardController.js']);
                        }]
                }
            })
            .state('dashboard', {
                parent: 'index',
                url: '/dashboard',
                views: {
                    'content': {templateUrl: 'app/modules/general/views/home.html', controller: 'DashBoardController'},
                },
                resolve: {
                    dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                        function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['app/modules/general/DashBoardController.js']);
                        }]
                },
                data:
                {
                    authenticated: true
                }
            })
            .state('users', {
                parent: 'index',
                url: '/users',
                views: {
                    'content': {templateUrl: 'app/modules/users/views/users.html', controller: 'UserController'},
                },
                resolve: {
                    dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                        function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['app/modules/users/UserController.js']);
                        }]
                },
                data:
                {
                    authenticated: true
                }
            })
            .state('forgotpassword', {
                parent: 'index',
                url: '/forgotpassword',
                views: {
                    'content': {templateUrl: 'app/modules/authenticate/views/forgot-password.html', controller: 'LoginController'},
                },
                resolve: {
                    dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                        function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['app/modules/authenticate/LoginController.js']);
                        }]
                },
                data:
                {
                    authenticated: true
                }
            })

            .state('reserpassword', {
                parent: 'index',
                url: '/reserpassword',
                views: {
                    'content': {templateUrl: 'app/modules/authenticate/views/reser-password.html', controller: 'LoginController'},
                },
                resolve: {
                    dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                        function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['app/modules/authenticate/LoginController.js']);
                        }]
                },
                data:
                {
                    authenticated: true
                }
            })

            .state('temp', {
                parent: 'index',
                url: '/temp',
                views: {
                    'content': {template: 'in', controller: 'DashBoardController'},
                },
                resolve: {
                    dep: ['$ocLazyLoad',
                        function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                            return $ocLazyLoad.load(['app/modules/general/DashBoardController.js']);
                        }]
                },
                data:
                        {
                            authenticated: true 
                        }
            });
});
```